# Define Cell style for Jquery-Jtable

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-jtable

After return result of  jquery-Jtable to client, Generate our needed fields at table tag , but i want to define css for last column of table or last my field in Jquery Jtable options, 
I mean The "status" column have background which :

```
if status==1 bgcolor:red , 

if status==2 bgcolor:green ,

if status==3 bgcolor:yellow ,
```

so I wrote this code :

```
fields: {
    Status: {
        title: 'RequestStatus',
        width: '4%',
        display: function( data ) {
            ???
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear with what you want?

Comment: i edited this . please check it out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the jTable API reference, it looks like `listClass` may be what you are looking for to stylize individual table cells.

**listClass**,
string,
default: none

A string value that can be set as class/classes of a cell of this field (td element) in the table. Thus, you can stylize fields in the table.

http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference#fopt-listClass

Comment: In this case, td column will come right but header will stay left, as it is.. any way to move header right as well?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to allow custom styles on cells by using conditional logic: use the display option in jTable for each row  and field(Cell), The following code example demonstrates what I mean:

```
      <style> 
       .redCell
        {
        } 
      </style>

           //---attribute for J table fields   

       display : function(data){
                     if(data.record.status=="1" return "<div class='redCell'>" + data.record.StatusTitle +"</div>";
                     if ... 
                        ... 
                    }
```